# PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 on Drupal update.php

Tags: pdo, drupal-7

I'm trying to find a solution of this issue for hours but with no success so far. After I tried to update few modules to newest version in my Drupal 7 site earlier, I got an error on update.php page saying that there's some PDO failure.

Does anyone know what's causing this and how to solve it?

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.: SELECT name, schema_version FROM {system} WHERE type = :type; Array ( [:type] => module ) in drupal_get_installed_schema_version() (line 155 of /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxxx/httpdocs/includes/install.inc).
```

Line 155 of install.inc is the SELECT call:

```
if (!$versions) {
  $versions = array();
  $result = db_query("SELECT name, schema_version FROM {system} WHERE type = :type", array(':type' => 'module'));
  foreach ($result as $row) {
    $versions[$row->name] = $row->schema_version;
  }
}
```

Thanks for help, any clue is appreciated.

Comment: The error is quite descriptive

Comment: seems so, but how to inactivate the unbuffered queries?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is causing it but it might be worth to login to mysql and run `flush tables;` That should clear anything that is hanging.

Comment: Thank you for tip, unfortunately my hosting provider refused to run this command ..